# angularjs routing, multiple paths

Tags: angularjs

I have the following set up:

```
var userSystemApp = angular.module("userSystem",['userServices','groupServices']).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/user', {templateUrl: 'user/partials/userlist.html',   controller: 'userListController'}).
            when('/user/:userName', {templateUrl: 'user/partials/userdetail.html', controller: 'userDetailController'}).
            when('/group',{templateUrl: 'group/partials/grouplist.html', controller: 'groupListController'}).
            when('/group/:groupName', {templateUrl: 'group/partials/groupDetail.html', controller: 'groupDetailController'}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/user'});
    }]);
```

When I go to localhost/#/user the groupListController is activated. 
When I go to localhost/#/group the groupListController is activated but it uses the userlist.html partial template.

Why isn't it using the proper controller?  Am I fundamentally using routing and templates improperly?

(side note, I have mod_rewrite taking rewriting the blank path to index.html)

Comment: "When I go to localhost/#/user the groupListController is activated" did you mean the userListController is loaded?

Comment: No, that's why I'm confused.  When I look at the network tab on firebug it calls the service that the groupListController calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is an error where the controllers are defined.

It seems you have something like:

```
userSystemApp.controller('userListController', theFunction);
```

But `theFunction` instead of being the correct one, which returns the `userListController`, is by mistake the one which defines the `groupListController`.

Comment: Close enough. It turns out I didn't give you enough information. In the service definition I accidentally named the Group service User.  Stare at this stuff too long you go blind.